# How to add libraries from an enviornment variable in Netbeans 6

Tags: java, netbeans

If I have an environment variable named JAR_FILES with a semicolon separated list of jar files, is there a way to have Netbeans to automatically add all of these jar files to my project libraries so that I do not have to manually add each one? I ask because there are many and they are not in the same directory.

The only thing I can think of is to manually edit some of the build scripts (such as build.xml or those in nbproject), but I am assuming these may get overwritten by the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use your own Global Library? You can create a new one using the Library Manager (Tools->Libraries), you can add the required jars to it and then have all your projects use the same global library.

Comment: I know how to do that, but still you have to (once) add all of the files manually. Also, it could come out of sync should your environment variable change.